# Get the ObjC message parameter's value in a Checker implementation for Clang SA

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I'm new to the clang. In a checker I'm trying to implement, I want to fetch the value to the parameter 'attribute' passed to the following ObjC message to NSFileManager.

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:dfltFileData attributes:fileAttributes];
```

Once the 'fileAttributes' is obtained which is of type NSDictionary, then I need to get the value of the key 'NSFileProtectionKey'.  'fileAttributes' is declared as following.

```
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
```

By implementing the checker callback checkPostObjCMessag, I'm able to get the parameter 'attributes' as Expr.  **Now I'm not able to get the pointer or something to this object 'fileAttributes' using Expr object *en so that I can goto the declaration of 'fileAttributes' and check for key value pair I'm interested in.** The following is the code of my checker implementation.

```
    void FileManagerChecker::checkPreObjCMessage(const ObjCMethodCall &Msg, CheckerContext &C) const { 
        const ObjCInterfaceDecl * recv = Msg.getReceiverInterface (); 
        const StringRef name = recv->getIdentifier()->getName(); 
        Selector s = Msg.getSelector(); 
        StringRef first = s.getNameForSlot(0); 

        if(name.equals("NSFileManager")) { 
            if(first.equals("createFileAtPath")) { 
                const Expr *en = Msg.getArgExpr(2); 
                QualType ArgTy = en->getType(); 
                std::cout << "Qual type: " << ArgTy.getAsString() << std::endl; 
                std::cout << std::endl; 
                // find the variable having the attribute and check 
            } else if(first.equals("setAttributes")) { 
                // find the variable having the attribute and check 
            } else 
                ;   // should never get here 
         } 
    }
```

I think, I'm in the right direction/way. If not, please guide me a the better way of doing it.

Thanks a lot.